# Deleting a node from a linked list without getting an error?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

Simply, this program is to create a linked list of chars from a string. (say from "HELLO" to head->h->e->l->l->o->NULL)
Whenever I try to delete the head using my erase function, the program would stop working giving the "application.exe has stopped working... Windows is checking for a solution..". I think I might have problem with my memory allocation but I can't really tell. Suggestions greatly appreciated.

THIS WORKS

```
void StringADT::append(string s)
{ 
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    Node* NodePtr;
    Node* newNode;
    newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = s.at(i);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (!head)
    {
        head = newNode;
    } else
    {
        NodePtr = head;
        while (NodePtr->next)
        {
            NodePtr = NodePtr->next;
        }
        NodePtr->next = newNode;
    }
}
}

void StringADT::erase(int pos) //pos = position to erase

{
if (!head || pos < 0 || pos > length() - 1)
    return;
else {
    Node* NodePtr;  
    NodePtr = head;
    if (pos == 0)
    {   
        NodePtr = head->next;

        delete head; //PROBLEM COMES AFTER EXECUTION OF THIS LINE!!

    }
}
```

}

here is my class

```
class StringADT{

private:
    struct Node {
        char data;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
```

here is my append function which may be the root of the problem because of memory allocation.

```
void StringADT::append(string s) (appending string s to the linked list)
{ 
Node* NodePtr;

int slength = s.length();

Node *NodeArray;
NodeArray = new Node[slength];
if(!NodeArray)
    return;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    NodeArray[i].data = s.at(i);
    NodeArray[i].next = NULL;
}

if (!head)
{
    head = NodeArray;
    NodePtr = head;
    for(unsigned count = 1; count < slength; count ++)
    {
        NodePtr->next = (NodeArray + count);
        NodePtr = NodePtr->next;
        //cout << "number of count " << count << endl;
    }
} else {
    NodePtr = head;
    while (NodePtr->next)
    {
        NodePtr = NodePtr->next;
    }
    for(unsigned count = 0; count < slength; count ++)
    {
        NodePtr->next = (NodeArray + count);
        NodePtr = NodePtr->next;
        //cout << "number of count " << count << endl;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's wrong with std::list<char> and a function to append std::string?

Comment: I haven't gone through it completely..but at first glance you are allocating an array using `new[]` and try to delete one particular char from this which is not allowed.

Comment: @Naveen I think you are right. Do you have any suggestions about assigning the string to the linked list then? Thank you.

Comment: @AnotherTest could you elaborate for me please? I'm not familiar with this very much. I think I may be trying to delete a member of an array it seems like. Now I'm thinking of another way to append.

Comment: @LeonardLie: All the code you wrote is already present in standard library in much better quality, tested by thousands of people and bugs flushed out. So the first question when you present code like this is _why are you not just using standard library_?

Comment: @JanHudec I see your question. My task is to recreate or mimic string standard library by using Abstract Data Type. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @LeonardLie: Task by whom? And I don't see an abstract data type there anywhere.

Comment: @JanHudec by my professor.. :( Your assignment is to design a program to implement C++ string operations. You will implement this using a singly-linked list.
Recall that in c++ there is already a string class. You are to implement an alternative string class, called StringADT, that is implemented by a singly-linked list.
For example, to represent the string 'comp', you can use the following linked list.
_______ ______ ______ ______
head--> |_C|___|--> |_O|__|--> |_M|__|--> |_P|__|-->NULL

Answer (score 0):

The erase function should be like this:

```
if (pos == 0)
{   
    NodePtr = head;
    head = head->next;

    delete NodePtr;
}
```

Comment: @Chowlett.. oh sorry. My mistake. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @sgar91 I am still getting the error. I'm not sure if Naveen is right about my problem but I am trying to find a solution. Thanks for your help beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated your Node objects as follows:

```
NodeArray = new Node[slength];
```

What you have there is an *array* of Node objects *in one allocation*.  Later, when you're done *with a particular element* in that array, you're calling

```
    delete head; //PROBLEM COMES AFTER EXECUTION OF THIS LINE!!
```

to delete *a particular element of the array*.

This is not allowed in C++ memory allocation.

If you've allocated an array, you can only delete the entire array, not specific elements.  Moreover, you'll need to use the array delete[] operator, like this:

```
delete[] someArray;
```

But this gets to a fundamental problem with your design.  You're implementing a linked list, but you're allocating an array.  Now, in theory you can go ahead and allocate an array of linked list elements as you have done, but it doesn't make sense to do.  An array is allocated for a specific number of elements; a linked list is often used when you need an arbitrary number of elements and have no idea what that number is.

Linked lists usually have their elements allocated and deleted one at a time, rather than sitting in a pre-defined array.  When you get new data, you allocate a new node, then add it to the list.

(And the code smell above is, if you have an array, why do you need to link the elements?  You could just iterate to the next element instead of following pointers.  Arrays and linked lists just aren't used in combination; they have different purposes.  For your linked list you should get rid of the array and allocate individual nodes, then you can delete them individually as well.  You should not have that array at all.)

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is obviously that you allocate array of objects and than want to delete one of them. You have to allocate the `Node`s independently. I.e. it's the `append` function you need to fix.
2. The append should be written as `append(char)`, which just appends one char and than `append(string const &)` (strings may be expensive to copy, so always by reference, usually constant!) should just call that in a loop. And `append(char const *)`, so you can append string literals too!
3. Don't use indices for things that don't have random access. And so that you don't have to think what has direct access, simply learn to prefer iterating by iterators/pointers over iterating with index!

I won't give examples, because for assignment it's better if you come up with the actual code yourself, even if you have to repeatedly ask for clarification.

Comment: I will work on it. Thank you Sir. I appreciate your help. will return. The professor requires me to do
void append(string s); and overload void append(int n, char c) (which is simply append n n number of a character c to the end of the list

Comment: @LeonardLie: Fine. You should still implement them as loops just calling `append(char)` in each iteration. The node allocation is the difficult bit, so you definitely don't want to write that multiple times. And definitely use `std::string::const_iterator` for iterating over the string; iterating string with index is just as efficient, but iterators work on all standard library collections while indices don't.

Comment: @LeonardLie: And the const reference for string still stands. `append(string const &)` can be called in all ways `append(string)` can, but is more efficient in many.

Comment: I noticed that the new append I have on the original post works. but defining NodePtr and newNode everytime it iterates seems weird for me. Is it ugly in C++ World?

Comment: @LeonardLie: You need the nodes to be independent. You would have to allocate them independently in any language be it assembly, C, C++, Java or Python.

Comment: @LeonardLie: It is nice in the shiny high-level C++ world, but deep down at the bit-fiddling layers things are sometimes ugly. And unfortunately you need to know a bit about the low layers, because it has various high-level implications, usually for performance.

Comment: thank you for your dear help. I will get a copy of the conversation and clarify with my professor further (you are clear but i am just dumb :(  )  Well at least I got it working finally because of you! thanks again.